# Second CREATE page

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'd like to know if it's possible to have two different components (pages) for the create action on admin on rest.
I've tried to create a custom route (/videos/upload), with a custom page including the create component, but this failed, I guess because the component didn't get the necessary Resource data.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you read the Custom Routes documentation ? https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customroutes

Comment: Also, the Custom Actions documentation may help you getting the right data. https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Actions.html